# jelastic: copy files in apache tomcat bin folder

Tags: jsp, deployment, tomcat7, jelastic

I have deployed my web application in jelastic. My application interacts with an API that requires a licence. The licence files are to be copied in bin folder of Apache tomcat 7.
How do I copy licence files in the bin folder in jelastic? I need some assistance

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your files to bin folder from Jelastic Dashboard. Simply log into your account at app.j.layershift.co.uk, choose the Tomcat node in question, click on the wrench icon ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoWrR.png)) to get a file manager.

Navigate to JAVA_HOME > bin . There, hover the 'Upload' icon and choose the file from your local disk ([File Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE5nn.png)).